# How can I generate Random number picker that returns one of two two exact numbers with C#?

Tags: c#

In my case I want a way to get 1 or -1 randomly

I don't want any numbers in between

I couldn't get what I want using Random.Range() function.

Comment: `rand.Next(0,2) % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1;`

Comment: Or `rand.NextDouble() >= 0.5 ? 1 : -1;`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using:

```
var result = random.Next(0, 2) * 2 - 1;
```

This code will generate a 0 or 1, if it results to be 0, it would equal to -1 because

0*2=0 ------> 0-1=-1.

If it results to be 1, it will still be 1, because

1*2=2 ------> 2-1=1.